# Shiny - Can dynamically generated buttons act as trigger for an event

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny code that generates actions buttons from a numericInput and each of those actions buttons generate a plot when clicked using a observeEvent. The problem is that I don't know how to trigger an event with dynamically generated buttons. The workaround I used was to make a observeEvent for each button but if I generate more buttons than the obserEvents I created it won't work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic selectInput"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItemOutput("menuitem")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    numericInput("go_btns_quant","Number of GO buttons",value = 1,min = 1,max = 10),
uiOutput("go_buttons"),
plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menuitem <- renderMenu({
    menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
  })


  output$go_buttons <- renderUI({
    buttons <- as.list(1:input$go_btns_quant)
    buttons <- lapply(buttons, function(i)
      fluidRow(
      actionButton(paste0("go_btn",i),paste("Go",i))
      )
    )
  })

  #Can this observeEvents be triggerd dynamicly?
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("go_btn",1)]],{output$plot <-renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),breaks = 10)})})
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("go_btn",2)]],{output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),breaks = 50)})})
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("go_btn",3)]],{output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),breaks = 100)})})
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("go_btn",4)]],{output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),breaks = 200)})})
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("go_btn",5)]],{output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),breaks = 500)})})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also create observers dynamically. Just make sure that they are created only once, otherwise they will execute several times.

Below is your code modified to create as many observers as buttons. Please note that if an observer for the button already exist, it should not be created. You can customize your observers too, so each observer could have its own behavior.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic selectInput"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItemOutput("menuitem")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    numericInput("go_btns_quant","Number of GO buttons",value = 1,min = 1,max = 10),
uiOutput("go_buttons"),
plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menuitem <- renderMenu({
    menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
  })

  # to store observers and make sure only once is created per button
  obsList <- list()

  output$go_buttons <- renderUI({
    buttons <- as.list(1:input$go_btns_quant)
    buttons <- lapply(buttons, function(i)
      {
        btName <- paste0("go_btn",i)
        # creates an observer only if it doesn't already exists
        if (is.null(obsList[[btName]])) {
          # make sure to use <<- to update global variable obsList
          obsList[[btName]] <<- observeEvent(input[[btName]], {
            cat("Button ", i, "\n")
            output$plot <-renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100, 4, 1),breaks = 50*i)})
          })
        }
        fluidRow(
          actionButton(btName,paste("Go",i))
        )
      }
    )
  })

}
```

Comment: Works nice, thanks!
What if, instead of having several observEvents, I want to have an observe() that is triggered by any of the inputs[[]] generated?

Comment: It looks like an interesting question, I have some ideas of how to solve that, you could open a new question, so we don't make a mess here.

Comment: Ok, the new question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631788/shiny-observe-triggered-by-dynamicaly-generated-inputs