# How to identify which observer is being triggered in Shiny when multiple dynamic observers are in use

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, reactive

I have a set of dynamic UI forms being generated in tabs. I have used dynamic observeEvents to check which form is being saved.
Please see the code below

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("generate_tab","Generate Tabs"),
  tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
              uiOutput('tabsN')),
  dataTableOutput("saved_tabs_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv<- reactiveValues(no_of_tabs =0)

  #generating the UI dynamically
 observeEvent(input$generate_tab,{
   rv$no_of_tabs <- rv$no_of_tabs + 1
   appendTab(inputId = "tabs", 
             tabPanel(title = paste0("Tab_",rv$no_of_tabs),
             selectInput(paste0("Input",rv$no_of_tabs),paste0("Input",rv$no_of_tabs), choices = c('',LETTERS), selected = NULL),
             actionButton(paste0("submit_input",rv$no_of_tabs),"submit input")
             )
   )})

# Reading the inputs upon clicking of Submit Input in each tab
   #dynamic Observe Event needs to be set up dependent on number of Tabs (rv$no_of_tabs)

   observeEvent(lapply(paste0("submit_input",1:rv$no_of_tabs), function(x){input[[x]]

   }
   ),{
     rv$inputs <-sapply(paste0("Input",1:rv$no_of_tabs), 
                        function(x)input[[x]])

        },ignoreInit = TRUE  )



   output$saved_tabs_output <- renderDataTable({
     as.data.frame(rv$inputs) 
   })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

because multiple submit-button clicks are being checked in one observeEvent lapply formulation, it accepts inputs from non-submitted forms as well. Here is an example

Step 1: Hit Generate tabs 4 times to generate Tab1,Tab2,Tab3,Tab 4. Click Tab 1
[image]

Step 2: Select B in Tab 1. Do NOT press Submit
[image]

Step 3: Select D in Tab 4 and Hit Submit[image]

Desired output is that only Input4 is updated and not input1, however in this case, both B and D are saved. Any pointers as to how one can fix this?

Comment: It is much easier if you have only one observer to process all the clicks of the dynamically created elements. Look at these couple of examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631788/shiny-observe-triggered-by-dynamicaly-generated-inputs/40643541#40643541) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547786/shiny-can-dynamically-generated-buttons-act-as-trigger-for-an-event/40558301#40558301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geovany's comment helped. I was also helped by this [link](https://gist.github.com/mine-cetinkaya-rundel/0fe2a9830f7151e72053239e73350592).
The trick was to associate just one observer with each Submit button.

Here is the code that works, in case it is useful for anyone

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("generate_tab", "Generate Tabs"),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
              uiOutput('tabsN')),
  verbatimTextOutput("rvInput")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # browser()
  rv <- reactiveValues(no_of_tabs = 0L,
                       inputs = list()
                       )

  #generating the UI dynamically
  observeEvent(input$generate_tab, {
    rv$no_of_tabs <- rv$no_of_tabs + 1
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel(
                title = paste0("Tab_", rv$no_of_tabs),
                selectInput(
                  paste0("Input", rv$no_of_tabs),
                  paste0("Input", rv$no_of_tabs),
                  choices = c('', LETTERS),
                  selected = NULL
                ),
                actionButton(paste0("submit_input", rv$no_of_tabs), "submit input")
              ))
  })

  observe({
    lapply(1:rv$no_of_tabs, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("submit_input", x)]], {
        rv$inputs[[x]] <- input[[paste0("Input", x)]]
      })
    })
  })

  output$rvInput <- renderPrint({
    rv$inputs
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```